# ornstein-uhlenbeck process with normal initial value stochastic filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's take an input-output stochastic system with a given noise. First of all we should define the noise process so we will have:

$$d x_t=-\theta x_t d t+\sigma d W_t$$
where the $d W_t$ is a standard wiener process(Brownian motion).

Multiply $e^{\theta t}$ to both sides so we will have:

$$e^{\theta t}*d x_t+e^{\theta t} \theta x_t d t = e^{\theta t}* \sigma d W_t$$
$$d(x_t e^{\theta t}) =  e^{\theta t}\sigma dW_t$$
Without loss of generality take $X_0 = N(0,\sigma '^2)$, so then:

$$x_t e^{\theta t} =x_0 + \sigma \int e^{\theta s} dW_s$$
$$x_t(u)  =X_0 e^{-\beta t}+ \sigma \int_{0}^{u} e^{\theta (s-t)} dW_s$$

Now we define the noise as below:
$$N_t=\xi(t)=\int_0^t x(s) d s$$

How can I write $N_t$?

Comment: A little correction ($3$ mistakes) before I let you proceed. The solution of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE $dx_t=-\theta x_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t$ is 
$$
x_t=X_0e^{\color{red}{-\theta}t}+\sigma\int_0^{\color{red}{t}}e^{\color{red}{-}\theta(t-s)}\,dW_s\,.
$$
Can you work on an attempt to calculate $\int_0^tx_s\,ds\,?$

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, it was a typo. regradless of the term I have question about sure for the main term I can write :$$\int_0^t \sigma \int_0^s \exp \{-\theta(s-r)\} d W_r d s=\int_0^t \frac{\sigma}{\theta}\left(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)}\right) d W_s$$

Comment: Looks right. Stochastic Fubini.

Comment: do you have any idea what can I do with the initial value where it is a normal random variable?

Comment: $\int_0^tX_0e^{-\theta s}\,ds=X_0\frac{1-e^{-\theta t}}{\theta}\,.$

Comment: When X0 is a normal random variable isn't it different from a simple constant?

Comment: It is not a constant but it does not depend on the time variable over which we integrate.

Comment: Thanks and if we take it normal with N(0, sigma^2/2 theta)it will be stationary?

Comment: No. A lot of physicists and applied mathematicians confuse the two flavours of the OU process. The true story is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414621/a-gauss-markov-process-is-always-a-solution-to-a-langevin-type-sde/4414813#4414813).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @kasra for completeness, could you add your solution as an answer to this question?

Comment: That would be nice. Also: in the link I just gave I show that $x_t$ is not stationary. With the solution you found you should be able to show that $\int_0^tx_s\,ds$ is also not stationary, regardless how we simplify $X_0\,.$